# Is there a free "AutoTune" plugin for Audacity?

Tags: software-rec, audio, processing, audacity, autotune

I have plugged in [GSnap](http://www.gvst.co.uk/gsnap.htm) in Audacity. How do I get the "tune" effect shown in the video *[Auto Tuning](http://www.vimeo.com/3718294)*?

Comment: Does Audacity have capability to use VST plugins? I believe I've used a tool called "GSnap" before. I think that was it.  Didn't want to make this an answer, because I'm not sure.

Comment: @anonymous coward - I did use the gsnap plugin ... tried to configure it .. but I could not get it to work. Too lazy to read the documentation. Is there something simpler?

Comment: I can't get it to work either. When I change the settings nothing happens.

Comment: __[dear-gawd-whyyyyyy]__

Comment: This is why: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bduQaCRkgg4

Answer (score 6):

1. [Download the GSnap plug-in](http://www.gvst.co.uk/gsnap.htm) and choose "Download GSnap / Grymmjack skin (Size 310 KB, last modified 02 May 2007)" .
2. You will have a folder containing two icons, GSnap-GJ.dll and GVSTLicense.
3. Open `My Computer` -> `Local Disk` -> `Program Files` -> `Audacity` -> `Plug-ins` and copy `GSnap-GJ.dll` there (you should have Audacity 1.3 Beta (Unicode)).
4. Open Audacity and open an already recorded file.
5. Effect -> GSnap
6. Apply these settings:

   - MIN. FREQ 40 Hz
   - MAX. FREQ 2000 Hz
   - GATE (-80)dB
   - SPEED 1
   - THRESH 100 cents
   - AMOUNT 90%
   - ATTACK 1ms
   - RELEASE 1ms
   - P.BEND 0 cents
   - VIBRATO 0 cents
   - VIB. SPEED 0.1HZ
   - CALIBRATE 430 Hz
   - INPUT SOURCE TRACKING : FIXED
   - CONFIGURE :  Key : G   Scale : Major
   - and Check "Set Threshold to Fill Gaps"
7. The effect will be applied and play the track.

P.S: If you had no change to the voice, apply the effect many times.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the VST bridge is in the correct plug-in folder. It automatically installed it into the wrong folder so Gsnap would show up in Audacity but would nt do anything. Check to see if you have two audacity folders in your program files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've turned on the setting in effect, preferences. You'll find it under edit, or just use the shortcut ctrl+p

I spent a while wondering why it wouldn't realise I had the gsnap in my plugin folder. Also if you have audacity 1.3 up you dont need the VST enabler that some of the posts were about. It doesn't hurt if you have got it in there though.

After that its just a matter of how well can you play around with the settings: P

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get Audacity to read [VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) with the VST-bridge plug-in. However, GSnap is almost unusable in Audacity.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Audacity VST Enabler](http://audacityteam.org/vst/), and make sure you put it in the plug-ins folder in Audacity 1.3.9.